# How to emulate Windows CE 5.0 on ARMV4i architecture

Tags: windows-ce, arm, emulation

I am developing Qt application for Windows CE 5.0 device.

My setup is:
Qt 4.7.3 compiled with Visual Studio 2005 using Windows CE 5.0 Standard SDK.

Everything works OK on real device, though I would like to test software "locally" in an emulator.

Visual Studio 2005 provides Pocket PC 2003, Windows Mobile 6 emulator images but no Windows CE 5.0.

Windows Microsoft CE 5.0 Emulator does that, but its sample device is based on i486, so this doesn't work for me...

I found *some kind* "Plaftorm Builder" and "ARMV4i BSP for Windows CE 5.0", but I am not building device or it's SDK, and I am not interested in specific device at all. All i need is "generic" AMRv4 WinCE 5 image for basic testing...

So what is possible outcomes for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microssoft stopped providing Windows CE OS images for the emulator after the x86 emulator was abandoned, and for good reason.  Windows CE is a modular OS so it's not possible to create an Emulator OS image that matches what all devices are and my guess is that there were too many support calls and complaints about how the emulator either contained something unwanted or didn't contain something that was wanted.  The point being that there is no "generic Windows CE device" so there's no way to create an emulator of one.

The response from Microsoft was to provide the ARM-based Device Emulator 3.0 (available as a [Standalone Release](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5352)) and a [BSP for the emulator](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=18385) so developers can create their own OS images that match their actual target hardware OSes.

So your options are to either create an OS yourself or find an OEM that provides an emulator image for their device (I'm not aware of one offhand, but I very, very rarely use the emulators so I've never bothered to look).